# VBA Sorting Data in two phases

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have got a table 
[image]

And I dont know how to sort the data in way which i need.

The result which I want is here:
[image]

And at the beggining I want to sort the column number 2 where are Animal and IT then after that i want to sort from A to Z only data where in second column is Animal, then sort data where in the second column is 'IT'.

I have found only one way how could I do it.

And... To sort the data by second column I can use

```
Range("A1:B6").Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending
```

But what after that? I think about... Write a loop which will go through the column 2 and for example. Will start from 1 (Animal) and go next... will be for example other value (IT), it will read number of record and -1 (in this example it will be 3). Then add fuction sort data in range.

I dont know if it will work...

Do you have maybe other ideas how to do it?

Comment: Do you know how to do it with the mouse? (over the data-tab -> sort) then record a macro and go from there

Comment: I have got milions of records.

Comment: So? Start recording a Macro, Highlight Column A and B, go to the Data-Tab -> Sort the way you want to sort, stop recording the macro. Look at what was recorded and adjust it to your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the following Sub and call it when you have any new data:

```
Public Sub sort_()
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.sort Key1:=Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("A1"), Order2:=xlAscending
End Sub
```